# Multiple Sensor data Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-sensors

Hi i have a big problem too get data from multiple Sensors
my code for register and read data is:

```
    [Service]
    class BackgroundServiceSensoren : Service
    {
     StepDetector sd;
     Azimut az;
    double obererSchwellenWert = 2.0;
      double untererSchwellenWert = -2.0;
     Boolean timerFlag = false;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
      public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
        sd = new StepDetector(obererSchwellenWert, untererSchwellenWert, timerFlag, 0);
            az = new Azimut();

            var mSensorManager1 = (SensorManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);
            var mSensorManager2 = (SensorManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);
            var mLinearAccelerometer = mSensorManager1.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.LinearAcceleration);
           // mSensorManager1.RegisterListener(sd, mLinearAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Fastest);
            var mAzimutMagneticField = mSensorManager2.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
            var mAzimutAccelerometer = mSensorManager2.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);

          mSensorManager2.RegisterListener(az, mAzimutMagneticField, SensorDelay.Game);
              mSensorManager2.RegisterListener(az, mAzimutAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Fastest);


        });
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

class Azimut : Java.Lang.Object, ISensorEventListener
{
    float [] mGravity;
    float [] mGeomagnetic;
    float azimut;



    public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
    {

    }

 public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        Sensor mySensor = e.Sensor;

        if (mySensor.Type == SensorType.Accelerometer)
        {
            if (mGravity == null)
            {
                mGravity = new float[3];
            }
            e.Values.CopyTo(mGravity, 0);


        }
        if (mySensor.Type == SensorType.MagneticField)
        {
            if(mGeomagnetic == null){
                mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
            }
            e.Values.CopyTo(mGeomagnetic,0);


        }

        if (mGeomagnetic != null && mGravity != null)
        {
            float[] R = new float[9];
            float[] I = new float[9];
            bool success = SensorManager.GetRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success)
            {
                float[] orientation = new float[3];
                SensorManager.GetOrientation(R, orientation);
                azimut = orientation[0];
                Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, azimut.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

But I get only the Values from Accelerometer, but how can I get the Values from Accelerometer and MagneticField

Comment: what API level you are trying to test?

Comment: my min api is 15 but i test it on a 23

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about permissions on API 23 but on my old phone I get both notifications:

```
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity, ISensorEventListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var mSensorManager = (SensorManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);
        var mAzimutMagneticField = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
        var mAzimutAccelerometer = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);
        if (mAzimutMagneticField != null)
            mSensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mAzimutMagneticField, SensorDelay.Fastest);
        if (mAzimutMagneticField != null)
            mSensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mAzimutAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Fastest);
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
    {

    }

    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.MagneticField)
        {
            var magn = e.Values[0];
        }
        if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Accelerometer)
        {
            var acc = e.Values[0];
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

Comment: For what is this   public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

Comment: This is function of ISensorEventListener. You have to implement it if you implement ISensorEventListener

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Its the same Issue everytime i run the Application only one sensor work.

Comment: Check if mAzimutMagneticField is returning an info about your sensor. May be you don't have this sensor on phone you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

ok I have the Solution
the old code:

```
   mSensorManager2.RegisterListener(az, mAzimutMagneticField, SensorDelay.Game);
   mSensorManager2.RegisterListener(az, mAzimutAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Fastest);
```

the new code:

```
   mSensorManager2.RegisterListener(az,(Sensor) mAzimutMagneticField, SensorDelay.Game);
   mSensorManager2.RegisterListener(az,(Sensor)mAzimutAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Fastest);
```

I don't know why the sensor need to cast to Sensor but it works for me